# Best way to start making Magento 2 themes

Tags: magento2, theme, best-practice, less-css, ui-library

I have done the research about it and found many solutions I tried some of them and came up with results successfully.

In my study, I have found that Magento 2 comes with its built-in CSS library and its own grid also.

But, I am a very big fan of bootstrap, some of them suggested that as well,  and showed me the path how to take bootstrap into magento's luma theme.

So, my question here is what is the best practice, shall i invest my time in integrating bootstrap and making it from scratch with bootstrap. Or should i invest my time in learning magento's design framework?

Comment: I don't think you can call this 'best practice' as it all depends on what you need. If you require more functionality that the magento2 built in 'framework' you obviously have to use something else. Even if it is only so you can do your work more efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

You can do simple thing. There is default themes available like blank and Luma. you can copy it and make new theme and make changes as per your requirment. ofcourse you should have knowledge of magento framework and you should know how to work with theme.

For that you can see video tutorial available on Magento U and there is also some good blog available for same.

**Update:**

As mention by @tecjam you can use child theme features and just copy files which required modification.

Good luck

Comment: Personally I would not do this. I would make a child theme and only copy those files over you actually want to edit.

Comment: @tecjam you are absolutely right. I've not mentioned for child theme.

Comment: You're right, I already did that and came up with correct results as I mentioned it in my question. Here I am asking is that, that whether I start learning Magento's default framework or I invest my time to make it work with bootstrap.

Comment: @SoebSafi You should learn Magento framework first.

Comment: @Dip you're getting me wrong i think, or i guess i have said it in a confusing way. I actually know magento framework, here i am talking about theme css framework (The GrId) and other elements.